# How to fix SyntaxError when reading sqlite3 database into a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'am trying to read sqlite3 database using pandas. Unfortunately in my code is SyntaxError but i can't find it.

The code is the same as in many tutorials so i don't know where is the problem

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("activity_log.db")
query = "SELECT * from log"
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)

print(df)

con.close()
```

result:

```
" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/g50-45/Desktop/ML/1z10_webapp/data_analyser.py", line 7, in <module>
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)

  File "C:\Users\g50-45\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 325, in read_sql_query
    pandas_sql = pandasSQL_builder(con)

  File "C:\Users\g50-45\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 575, in pandasSQL_builder
    if _is_sqlalchemy_connectable(con):

  File "C:\Users\g50-45\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 44, in _is_sqlalchemy_connectable
    import sqlalchemy

  File "C:\Users\g50-45\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.sql import (

  File "C:\Users\g50-45\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import (

  File "C:\Users\g50-45\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\expression.py", line 2452

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax "
```

Comment: can you check what version of pandas you are using, and also sqlalchemy ?

Comment: is the sqlite database accessible via the folder structure? What happens if you connect to memory and try to write to it. does it still give you an error? `con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')`. By checking if its a memory problem or not, it can help us narrow down where the error is coming from

Comment: I didn't think about it.
I updated the pandas from 0.25.0 to 0.25.1 and sqlalchemy from 0.7.10 to 1.3.8.
Now everything works as it should.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sqlalchemy package looks like 6 years old (`sqlalchemy\sql\expression.py.py", line 2452`), before an important refactoring.

You should remove this package and reinstall it with a newer version or try an update with:

```
pip install SQLAlchemy --upgrade
```

Comment: As you said .
Upgrade was solution to my problem.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice! you're welcome. i saw it in the same time i push the answer